# Setup Trezor with Electrum. Created a receiving address. Executed from my online wallet. Timed out and disconnected Trezor. Now what?

Tags: electrum, trezor

I setup Trezor 1 (not Model T) with Electrum, then created a receiving address in Electrum (not Trezor's wallet). I then sent transfer from Paxos account to this address. However, Paxos triggered some confirmation of transaction, and Trezor+Electrum had a 5 min time out. I had to disconnect Trezor and fire Electrum back up. I don't see transaction history in Electrum or the receiving address referenced anywhere. Now what?

Answer (score 1):

You can see the full list of addresses on the addresses tab of electrum. If you can't see this tab go to view menu > show addresses. You can search the list by pressing ctrl+f. Search for the missing address there.

Answer (score 0):

This resolved. However, it was significantly delayed by Paxos. Another reason to get out of the exchanges quickly.

As far as I can tell Electrum does not save the addresses created which hella annoying. Please correct me if I'm being dumb.

Answer (score 0):

Electrum generates addresses deterministically. That means that the first address it generates based on your seed will always be the same **as long as it is unused**. As soon as Electrum sees a transaction on that address (regardless of whether it has been confirmed or not), it will never again generate that receive address.

As to why the transaction was not show in your history in Electrum: this is due to Paxos not immediately processing the actual Bitcoin transaction as soon as you confirm your withdrawal.

Comment: That makes sense. The weird thing that remains is that there is no visualization of that receiving address, whether used or not, once it times out or if you get disconnected. No log, history, console command that dumps the info. So in the case you get disconnected...poof...you're left wondering if you keyed the wrong address on the other end. Only solution I can think of is to screen shot it unless I'm looking in the wrong place? 

And you're correct about paxos not immediately executing trans. Hence the reason I'm bailing out, among many others.